# Jquery click function returning to start

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function below, which hides or shows a DIV when an element is clicked. However, it's being ran twice on a single mouseclick. I've used firebug to stop the code at a few breakpoints, and when the last function (slideToggle) is finished, it returns back to the start of the click function and repeats one more time. This means the element that was meant to be shown, is still hidden as it hides it again on the slideToggle.

```
$('#showEmailHistory').click(function() {
    $('#emailHistory').siblings().slideUp();
    $('#emailHistory').slideToggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I've placed an event.stopPropagation(); as a temporary measure to fix this. But what i'd really like to know is what's causing it to re-run? There are no other events linked to the element #showEmailHistory.

The element linked to the click is a simple div.

```
<div id="showEmailHistory" class="button">Show Email History</div>
```

The element i'd like to show is a simple div.

```
<div id="emailHistory">
    Content
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html you're running it on? It would make it a lot easier to explain...

Comment: You need to show us where you're binding the event, and what could cause the event to be bound twice. The function itself is of less importance, all though you could just do: `$('#emailHistory').slideToggle().siblings().slideUp();`. You are of course not using the same ID twice ?

Comment: From your description is it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xmajox/VQgNS/ ?

Comment: Oh, and btw: why don't you use a <button> element to act as a button?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to refer your "event" variable as a param function. Something like this:

```
$('#showEmailHistory').click(function(event) {
    $('#emailHistory').siblings().slideUp();
    $('#emailHistory').slideToggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Funny thing is, i've never had to do this before. It's only recently that it's started re-running after the last function. It used to work fine without the event.stopPropagation();.

Comment: @RoverK Your call to `event.stopPropagation()` isn't doing anything because the function doesn't know what `event` refers to - you need to specify a name (`event`) for the argument being passed to the callback.

Comment: True. The reason why it's stopping may be because it's erroring out and not because it's actually stopping the propagation. From your description it doesn't seem to be a click propagation issue.

Comment: Anthony, fair enough it may not be doing anything but it's doing something to stop the re-run at least and is working as a temp fix.

Comment: Double checked, You're right, it's stopping because it's causing an error seen in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the answer. The page has a duplicate  with duplicate script tags meaning the script was being ran twice. Thanks goes to my colleague who let that happen.

Answer (score -1):

This works without any double call. http://jsfiddle.net/jazaret/C6JsH/

```
$('#showEmailHistory').click(function() {
    $('#emailHistory').siblings().slideUp();
    $('#emailHistory').slideToggle();
});​
```

The double fire problem usually occurs when the click event is tied to a class that is matched  on and above the DOM element that is triggered.  If you could provide the specific DOM elements or a subset on jsfiddle perhaps we can identify the issue better?

Comment: This isn't an answer; you're saying "This works with the information provided, please provide more" which should be posted as a *comment*.